# Extend a SKSpriteNode in One direction only

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode, sknode

I am working on a project in `SpriteKit` using `swift` and I can't seem to create a progress bar that will stretch in one direction. If I use the below it expands in both directions from it position.

```
    // Extend Bar (SKSpriteNode) on touch
    if touched {
        bar.size.height+=20
    } else if !touched && bar.size.height > 10 {
        bar.size.height-=20
    }
```

What is the best way to achieve this? I have also tried yScale with the same issue.

I thought of adding a new `SKSpriteNode` to a `SKnode` group to make the progress and then removing from the the array to go back down, but this seems overkill and I was hoping there was a simpler approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is simple. Set the node's `anchorPoint` to (0,0) (or any of the other 3 corners).

Comment: Damn. Nice one. Thanks for that.